# Need Help Formatting a HTML Page Layout

Tags: css, html

I have a page that I want to have the following format: [image]

I am having problems getting the lower page navigation positioned properly. It needs to always be below the data columns. It currently wraps below the left column. It is supposed to have a border around it, but the border is appearing near the top of the page. Lastly the footer appears at the top of the page and not the bottom. I've been playing with this for over a day and can't figure out where I made my mistakes.

A stripped down version of the code is here:

```css
.h2b {
  /*page title*/
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  color: #469;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.a {
  color: #469;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
#masthead {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c5d5e5;
  /*width: auto;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#page_content {
  position: relative;
  width: 96%;
  /*width: 98%;*/
  /*border-top-width: 1px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #CCAA77;*/
  left: 20px;
}
#major_revision {
  /*position: relative;
 left: 20px;*/
}
#footer {
  background-color: #dfcfbf;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
#masthead img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#masthead p {
  font-size: small;
  text-align: right;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Styles for Navigationcommon modified 10-16-2015*/

#navigationcommon {
  background-color: #548EBE;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: thin black solid;
}
#navigationcommon ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navigationcommon li {
  float: left;
}
#navigationcommon a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  background-color: #548EBE;
}
#navigationcommon a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
/* Styles for Footer */

#footer p {
  font-size: x-small;
  text-align: center;
  color: #393939;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 1px;
}
#footer a {
  color: #393939;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>PAGE</title>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Begin Container -->
  <div id="container">

    <!-- Begin Masthead -->
    <header id="masthead" onclick="" style="background-color:#0047ff">
      <p style="background-color:#0047ff;height:30px; width:104px">
        <!--See helper file for paths to image files-->
      </p>
    </header>
    <!-- End Masthead -->
    <nav id="navigationcommon" onclick="">
      <ul>
        <!--See helper file for paths to image files-->
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="passdata(); return false">Improve</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tailor</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" style="float:right;font:small-caption;border-style:none;
  color:white; vertical-align:bottom;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">Advanced Search</a>
      <!--See helper file for paths to image files-->
      <input type="image" src="pill-button-green-clip-art.jpg" style="width: 90px; border-style:none; float:right; height: 28px;" value="Search" onclick="search()">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="512" id="search" class="searchField" title="" style="width: 300px; 
  border-style:none; height: 26px; float:right; padding-right:5px; " value="Enter Keyword">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </nav>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <section id="page_content" style="top: 60px;" onclick="">
      <div id="major_revision" style="position:fixed;top: 65px;float:left;width:100%;padding: 0 1% 1% 2%;">
        <p><span id="area" style="font-weight:bold">Some Data</span>
          <br>
          <span style="font-size:x-small">Major Revision: <revision>1.0</revision><!-- Format  is Major Revision: #.# -->
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Date: <date>7/1/2015</date></span>
        </p>
        <!-- Format  is Release Date: mm/dd/yyyy -->
      </div>
      <!-- Below is for the navigation buttons on the top of the screen. It goes ABOVE the LEFT COLUMN <div> -->
      <div style="position:fixed;top: 120px;width:96%;margin:0 0 0 2%;border:thin black solid">

        <!---->
        <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:50%;padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;background-color:#CCDDFF">
          <p style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;margin:.5% 0 .5% 1%;">
            <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF" name="previous" id="previous" type="button" value="&lt;&lt; Prev" onclick="page_navigation('previous')" class="round" />
            <br>
            <span style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-left:1%;" id="previous_text" class="style_bold"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative;float:right;width:50%;padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;background-color:#CCDDFF">
          <p style="text-align:right;background-color:transparent;margin:.5% 1% .5% 0;">
            <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF" name="next" id="next" type="button" value="Next &gt;&gt;" onclick="page_navigation('next')" class="round" />
            <br>
            <span style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-right:1%;" id="next_text" class="style_bold"></span>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Above is for the navigation buttons on the top of the screen -->

      <div style="position:fixed;top: 165px;float:left;width:98%;padding: 10px 0% 0% 2%;">
        <span class="h1b">Page Title
   </span>
      </div>

      <!-- Begin Left Column -->
      <div style="position:fixed;top: 205px;width:95%">
        <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:70%;padding: 0% 0% 1% 2%;">

          <span class="h2b">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
          <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>

            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
          </p>

          <span class="h2b">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
          <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:20px;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</span> 
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx.
            <br>
            <br>xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx</p>

        </div>
        <!-- End Left Column -->
        <!-- Begin Right Column -->
        <div style="position:relative;float:right;width:10%;margin:0 2% 0 0">
          <span class="h2b">xxxxxxx </span>
          <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>
            <br>xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br>

            <span style="margin:1%;">- xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:1%;">- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:1%;">- xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx</span>
            <br>
            <span style="margin:1%;">- xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx</span>
            <br>
            <br>

          </p>


          <!-- End Right Column -->
        </div>

        <!-- Below is for the navigation buttons on the bottom of the screen. It goes BELOW the RIGHT COLUMN </div> -->
        <div style="position:relative;width:100%;margin:0 0 0 2%;border:thin red solid">
          <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:50%;padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;background-color:#CCDDFF">
            <p style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;margin:.5% 0 .5% 1%;">
              <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF" name="previous" id="previous1" type="button" value="&lt;&lt; Prev" onclick="page_navigation('previous')" class="round" />
              <br>
              <span style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-left:1%;" id="previous_text1" class="style_bold"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div style="position:relative;float:right;width:50%;padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;background-color:#CCDDFF">
            <p style="text-align:right;background-color:transparent;margin:.5% 1% .5% 0;">
              <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF" name="next" id="next1" type="button" value="Next &gt;&gt;" onclick="page_navigation('next')" class="round" />
              <br>
              <span style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-right:1%;" id="next_text1" class="style_bold"></span>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Above is for the navigation buttons on the bottom of the screen -->
      </div>

    </section>
    <!-- Begin Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- End Footer -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->

</body>

</html>
​
```

Comment: Why are you using so many fixed positioned elements in your example?
Do they really need to be fixed?

Comment: this is too much confusing , a lot of inline CSS

Comment: If using "float", you also should "clear"!
Put left and right column into a container and clear it afterwards (f.e. with a clearfix class)

Comment: Why are you making up your own elements? Do you have any idea how dangerous that is?

Comment: 1. No they don't need to be fixed.
2. The inline css is so I can work through what the formatting needs to be.
3. Not sure what you mean by "clear"
4. The custom elements are there because the page gets parsed by an external tool that needs to extract certain elements for a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your building a complicated app, generally I use absolute layouts for the type of complexity that your layout represents:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BomePJ

```
<div class="l-masthead">Masthead</div>
<div class="l-navigation">Navigation</div>
<div class="l-revision">Revision</div>
<div class="l-pagenav-top">Page Navigation Top</div>
<div class="l-data">
  <div class="l-data-con">
    <div class="l-data1">
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum2
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="l-data2">
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum2
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorum1
      </p>     </div>
   </div>  
</div>
<div class="l-pagenav-bot">Page Navigation Bottom</div>
<div class="l-footer">Footer</div>


.l-masthead      { width:100%; height:20px; top:0; left:0; position:absolute; background:orange; }
.l-navigation    { width:100%; height:20px; top:20px; left:0; position:absolute; background:green; }
.l-revision      { width:100%; height:20px; top:40px; left:0; position:absolute; background:lime; }
.l-pagenav-top   { width:100%; height:20px; top:60px; left:0; position:absolute; background:yellow; }

.l-data          { width:100%; position:absolute; top:80px; bottom:40px; left:0; }
.l-data-con      { width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; }
.l-data1         { padding:20px; overflow-y:auto; position:absolute; top:0; right:50%; bottom:0; left:0; background:LightBlue; }
.l-data2         { padding:20px; overflow-y:auto;position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:50%; background:LightCyan; }

.l-pagenav-bot   { width:100%; height:20px; position:absolute; bottom:20px; left:0; background:yellow; }
.l-footer        { width:100%; height:20px; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; background:orange; }
```

This will be responsive down to a tablet form factor after that, with the type of complexity I think you are going to build in the app, it won't make sense.  You will have to go back to UX to make complex apps like this work from phone.

Also, get your CSS out of inline and into an external CSS file.

Comment: If I understand your markup, you are allowing each column to scroll and maintaining the bottom navigation and footer to be absolutely positioned. The requirements I am developing too were that the columns did not scroll. The page scrolled so that the navigation is not always visible. I will propose your recommendation to the team, however is there a way to do what I want within my current requirements?

Comment: Which navigation is not always visible?  You need to be more specific.  I can tweak the layout if I know exactly which elements stay in place and which ones scroll.

Comment: The whole page scrolls. Nothing is always visible. One thing I didn't include in my code, just to keep it simple, is that we have a slideout navigation menu that is always visible. However for what I have provided, nothing remains visible as the page scrolls.

Comment: If the whole page scrolls and nothing is sticky then you shouldn't be using any "fixed" divs.  All layout divs should be display:block.  The two data columns should be floated left and their container should be clear fixed.

Comment: So I'm trying both my original method AND yours. With mine, I can change the float for the right column to Float:Left and it takes care of the menu bar splitting, however if I add a border to the div that surrounds the both navigation buttons, the border appears above all of the page content and not around the buttons. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: With yours, it works fine except when I incorporate the sliding navigation I mentioned. The navigation can grow until it expands below the page, however the page does not provide a scroll bar when it does.

Comment: This is probably a separate questions.  I would need to see the html/css for the problem you have.  You can either start a new question or append to the existing one.

Comment: New topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223337/need-help-getting-page-to-scroll

Comment: If you think this answer was correct please select it as accepted.  Glad you got this working better!