# Border Not Appearing in Correct Position

Tags: html, css

This is a follow on to the previous formatting questions I posted.

[Need Help Getting Page to Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223337/need-help-getting-page-to-scroll/33223556#33223556)

[Need Help Formatting a HTML Page Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215200/need-help-formatting-a-html-page-layout?noredirect=1#comment54235877_33215200)

In this version I am using relative divs. The problem is with my top and bottom page navigation divs. The data within the enclosing divs appears in the correct position HOWEVER the border does not appear correctly. The border for the top navigation div appears above the "major_revision" section. The border for the bottom navigation div appears as a single line above the bottom navigation div.

```js
//<![CDATA[


function search(){

var text = document.getElementById('search').value;
  
if (text == "Keyword"){
 
     window.open("https:\\www.google.com");
     
} else {
   
    window.open("https:\\www.google.com&q="+text);
}
}

function passdata(){

 var x = document.title;
 var topic = get_meta_data("topic_area");
 
 if (x.substring(0,5) == "About" ||  x.substring(0,10) == "Contact Us" ||x.substring(0,3) == "FAQ")
 {
  topic = "";
  
 } else {

       topic = topic.replace("<topic>", "");
       topic = topic.replace("</topic>", "");
       topic = topic.replace("Topic Area: ", "");
 }
 
 if (topic == x || topic == ""){
  topic = "";
 }else{
  topic = ":" + topic;
 }
 
 if (x == "Testing")//<!--Mandatory-->
 {
  window.location = "improvement_request/improvement_request.html?" + x + topic;
 }else{
  window.location = "../improvement_request/improvement_request.html?" +  x + topic;
 } 
 
}

function populate_topic_area()
{
 
 document.getElementById('topicarea').innerHTML = get_meta_data("topic_area");
 
}

function get_meta_data(the_meta_tag)
{
 var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

 var answer = "" 

    for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) 
    { 
       if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == the_meta_tag) 
       { 
        answer = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
        
        
        break;
       } 
 }
return answer;
}

var query = window.location.search;
// Skip the leading ?, which should always be there, 
// but be careful anyway
if (query.substring(0, 1) == '?') 
{
     query = query.substring(1);
}
 
var data = query.split(','); 
for (i = 0; (i < data.length); i++) 
{
     data[i] = unescape(data[i]);
}
  
function CreateURLArray()
{
urlarray= new Array(11)
urlarray [0]= new Array(5)
urlarray [0]=["Testing","subpages/Previous_page.html","Previous","subpages/next_page.html","Next"] //The Page
urlarray [1]= new Array(5)
urlarray [1]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [2]= new Array(5)
urlarray [2]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [3]= new Array(5)
urlarray [3]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [4]= new Array(5)
urlarray [4]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [5]= new Array(5)
urlarray [5]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [6]= new Array(5)
urlarray [6]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [7]= new Array(5)
urlarray [7]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [8]= new Array(5)
urlarray [8]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [9]= new Array(5)
urlarray [9]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
urlarray [10]= new Array(5)
urlarray [10]=["","","","",""] //The Page,The Previous URL,What is displayed for the previous URL,The Next URL,What is displayed for the next URL
}


function handlerFunctions() {

 var x = document.title;
 var previous_url = '';
 var previous_text = '';
 var next_url = '';
 var next_text = '';
 
 for (i=0; i<10; i++) 
    { 
       if (urlarray [i][0]== x) 
       {        
        previous_url = urlarray [i][1];
   previous_text = urlarray [i][2];
   next_url = urlarray [i][3];
   next_text = urlarray [i][4]; 
     
        break;
       } 
 }
  
 function handlerFunctionPrev()
 {
  location.href = previous_url;
 }
 
 function handlerFunctionNext()
 {
  location.href = next_url;
 }
 
 if (previous_url == "")
 {
  document.getElementById('previous_text').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('previous_text1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('previous').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('previous1').style.display = "none";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById('previous_text').innerHTML = previous_text;
  document.getElementById('previous_text1').innerHTML = previous_text;
  document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener ('click',handlerFunctionPrev,false);
  document.getElementById('previous1').addEventListener ('click',handlerFunctionPrev,false);
 }
  
 if (next_url == "")
 {
  document.getElementById('next_text').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('next_text1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('next').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('next1').style.display = "none";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById('next_text').innerHTML = next_text;
  document.getElementById('next_text1').innerHTML = next_text; 
  document.getElementById('next').addEventListener ('click',handlerFunctionNext,false); 
  document.getElementById('next1').addEventListener ('click',handlerFunctionNext,false);
 }
}

 
  
//]]>
 </script> 
 
<script type="text/javascript">

function start() {

 CreateURLArray();
 populate_topic_area();
 handlerFunctions();

}

window.onload = start;
```

```css
body {color: #000;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: small;font-style: normal;background-color: #fff;}
#container {width: 100%;margin: 0;background-color: #fff;position: relative;padding: 0;}
#masthead {text-align: right;width: 100%;background-color: #0047ff;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow: auto;}
#navigation {background-color: #ca7;overflow: hidden;width: auto;margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;clear: both;}
#page_content {position: relative;width: 96%;left: 20px;}
#footer {background-color: #dfcfbf;padding-bottom: 5px;width: auto;clear: both;overflow: auto;}
#masthead img {float: left;margin: 0;padding: 0;height:30px}
#masthead p {font-size: small;text-align: right;color: #000;margin: 0 0 0 0;padding: 0;background-color:#0047ff}
#navigation ul {list-style-type: none;width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#navigation li {float: left;}
#navigation a {color: #000;text-decoration: none;display: block;padding: 5px;border: 1px solid #ca7;background-color: #dc8;}
#navigation a:hover {color: #000;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #ed9;background-color: #ed9;}
#navigationcommon {background-color: #548EBE;overflow: hidden;border-bottom:thin black solid;}
#navigationcommon ul {list-style-type: none;width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#navigationcommon li {float: left;}
#navigationcommon li a {color:  #FFF;text-decoration: none;display: block;padding: 5px;border: 1px solid  #D3D3D3;background-color:  #548EBE;}
#navigationcommon a {float:right;font:small-caption;border-style:none;color:white;vertical-align:bottom;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px}
#navigationcommon li a:hover {color:  #000;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid  #D3D3D3;background-color:  #ADD8E6;}
#navigationcommon a:hover {color:  #000;text-decoration:underline;}
#major_revision{position:relative;float:left;width:100%;padding: 0 1% 1% 2%;}
#footer p {font-size: x-small;text-align: center;color: #393939;margin: 10px;padding: 1px;}
#footer a {color: #393939;text-decoration: underline;}
#footer a:hover {color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
.style_bold {font-weight: bold;}
#navigation_slideout {position: fixed;top: 85px;left: -340px;-webkit-transition-duration: .5s;-moz-transition-duration: .5s;-o-transition-duration: .5s;transition-duration: .5s;    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    -moz-border-radius: 5px;    border-radius: 5px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;}
#navigation_slideout:hover {  left: -39px;}
#navigation_slideout ul{ list-style: none;}
#navigation_slideout ul li {width:295px;height: auto;text-align: left;padding-top: 5px;font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 12pt;color:white;font-weight:bold;}
#navigation_slideout ul li a{color: #000;text-decoration: none;font-weight:bold;display: block;color:white;}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul{ width:auto;}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul li { width:auto;position:relative;left:-41px;}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul li a {width:auto;height:30px;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;font-family:  helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12pt;color:white;font-weight:bold;}
#navigation_slideout ul li.expanding{height: auto }
#navigation_slideout ul li ul li.expanding1{height: auto;}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul li.expanding2{height: auto;margin-left:10px;}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul li a.expanding1 { padding:0;margin:0;height: auto ;}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul li a.expanding2 {padding:0;height: auto ;}
#menu{ -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);transform: rotate(-90deg); font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 14pt;color:white;font-weight:bold; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;right:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px}
#menu a{ font-size: 14pt;color:white;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
table.nospacing {border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;    table-layout: fixed;} 
table.nospacing th, td { padding: 0;}
.menu-col{max-width: 30px;}
.round{border-radius: 25px;-moz-border-radius: 25px;-webkit-border-radius: 25px;}
.expanding  label{padding: 3px;padding-left: 25px;}
.expanding li > ul { left:-35px;position:relative;width:100%;}
.expanding input[type=checkbox] {display: none;}
.expanding input[type=checkbox] ~ ul {max-height: 0;max-width: 0;opacity: 0;overflow: hidden;white-space:nowrap;   -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;   -moz-transition:all .5s ease;   -o-transition:all .5s ease;   transition:all .5s ease; }
.expanding input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul {max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;opacity: 1;}
.expanding input[type=checkbox] + label:before{transform-origin:25% 50%;  border: 8px solid transparent;  border-width: 8px 12px; border-left-color: white;  margin-left: -20px;width: 0;height: 0;display: inline-block;text-align: center;content: '';color: #AAAFAB;   -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;   -moz-transition:all .5s ease;   -o-transition:all .5s ease;   transition:all .5s ease; position: absolute;margin-top: 1px;}
.expanding input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {transform: rotate(90deg);}
.expanding_30{margin-left:30px;}
.expanding_0{margin-left:0px;text-indent:-10px;}
.expanding_40{margin-left:40px;text-indent:-10px;}
.expanding_50{margin-left:50px;text-indent:-10px;}
.expanding_width_menu{width:295px;}
.h2b {font-size: 17.5pt;color: #469;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;}
.h1b {font-size: 20pt;color: black;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold}
.top-nav-but{position:relative;width:100%;margin:0 0 0 2%;border:thin red solid;display:block}
.bottom-nav-but{position:relative;width:100%;margin:0 0 0 2%;border:thin green solid}
.nav-but-left{position:relative;float:left;width:50%;padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;background-color:#CCDDFF}
.nav-but-left-p{text-align:left;background-color:transparent;margin:.5% 0 .5% 1%;}
.nav-but-right{position:relative;float:right;width:50%;padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;background-color:#CCDDFF}
.nav-but-right-p{text-align:right;background-color:transparent;margin:.5% 1% .5% 0;}
.topic_title{position:relative;float:left;width:98%;padding: 10px 0% 0% 2%;}
.page_content{width:98%;clear:both}
.left_column{position:relative;float:left;width:80%;padding: 0% 1% 1% 2%;}
.right_column{position:relative;float:left;width:15%;padding: 1%;}
.clearfix { content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 

<title>Testing</title>
<meta name="topic_area" content="Topic Area: <topic>Testing</topic>" /><!--Mandatory-->

 


</head>

<body>

<!-- Begin Container -->
<div id="container">

 <!-- Begin Masthead -->
 <header id="masthead" onclick="">
  <p style="background-color:#0047ff">
  <!--See helper file for paths to image files-->
  <img style="float:left" src="Left.jpg" alt="" height="30" width="155px" ><img style="float:right" src="right.jpg" 
  alt="" height="30" width="104px" ></p>
 </header>
 <!-- End Masthead -->
 <nav id="navigationcommon" onclick="">
  <ul>
  <!--See helper file for paths to image files-->
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Contacts</a></li>
   <li>
   <a href="improvement_request/improvement_request.html" onclick="passdata(); return false">Improve This Document</a></li>
   <li><a href="tailor_this/tailor_this.html">Tailor This Document</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <a href="#">Advanced Search</a>
  <!--See helper file for paths to image files-->
  <input type="image" src="pill-button-green-clip-art.jpg" style="width: 90px; border-style:none; float:right; height: 28px;"value="Search"  
  onclick="search()"> &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; 
  <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="512" id="search" class="searchField" title="" style="width: 300px; 
  border-style:none; height: 26px; float:right; padding-right:5px; " value="Keyword"  >&nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;
 </nav>

<div id="navigation_slideout" style="background-color:#548EBE;z-index:1"onclick="">
<table class="nospacing" style="border-style:none">
<tr>
<td>
<ul class="expanding_width_menu">
<li class="expanding_30"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="expanding_30"><a href="about/about.html">About</a></li>
<li class="expanding_30"><a href="contact/contacts.html" >Contacts</a></li>
<li class="expanding_30" style="display:none"><a href="faq/faqs.html" >FAQs</a></li>
<li class="expanding_30" style="display:none"><a href="#" >Topic Area PDF</a></li>
</ul>
<hr width="200px">
<ul class="expanding_width_menu">
<li class="expanding_40"><a href="#">Requirements</a></li>
<li class="expanding_50"><a href="#">Requirement 1</a></li>
<li class="expanding_50"><a href="#">Requirement 2</a></li>
<li class="expanding_50"><a href="#">Requirement 3</a></li>
<li class="expanding_50"><a href="#">Requirement 4</a></li>
</ul>
<hr width="200px">
<ul class="expanding_width_menu" style="position:relative">
<li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb1"><label class="expanding" for="cb1">How to Make a Sandwich</label>
<ul class="expanding expanding_40">
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Bread</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Vegetables</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Cheese</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Condiments</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Meats</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Fillings</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Preparation</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb2"><label class="expanding" for="cb2">How to Make a Sandwich</label>
<ul class="expanding expanding_40">
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Bread</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Vegetables</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Cheese</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Condiments</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Meats</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Fillings</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Preparation</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb3"><label class="expanding" for="cb3">How to Make a Sandwich</label>
<ul class="expanding expanding_40">
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Bread</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Vegetables</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Cheese</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Condiments</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Meats</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Fillings</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Preparation</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb4"><label class="expanding" for="cb4">How to Make a Sandwich</label>
<ul class="expanding expanding_40">
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Bread</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Vegetables</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Cheese</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Condiments</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Meats</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Fillings</a></li>
<li class="expanding2"><a class="expanding2" href="#" >Preparation</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="menu-col" style="border-left:medium;border-left-color:white;border-left-style:solid">
<p id="menu"><a href="#" onclick=";return false;">MENU</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 <!-- Begin Page Content -->
 <section id="page_content"  onclick="">
  <div id="major_revision">
   <p><span id="topicarea"  style="font-weight:bold"></span><br>
   <span  style="font-size:x-small">Major Revision: <revision>1.0</revision><!-- Format  is Major Revision: #.# -->
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Release Date: <release_date>7/1/2015</release_date></span></p><!-- Format  is Release Date: mm/dd/yyyy -->
  </div>
 <!-- Below is for the navigation buttons on the top of the screen. It goes ABOVE the LEFT COLUMN <div> -->
  <div class="top-nav-but clearfix">
  
  <!---->
    <div class="nav-but-left">
     <p class="nav-but-left-p">
     <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF" name="previous" id="previous" type="button" value="&lt;&lt; Prev"onclick="page_navigation('previous')" class="round"/><br>
     <span  style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-left:1%;" id="previous_text" class="style_bold"></span>
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-but-right">
     <p class="nav-but-right-p">
      <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF"  name="next" id="next" type="button" value="Next &gt;&gt;"onclick="page_navigation('next')" class="round"/><br>
      <span style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-right:1%;" id="next_text" class="style_bold"></span>
     </p>
    </div>
 
  </div>
  <!-- Above is for the navigation buttons on the top of the screen -->
  
  <div class="topic_title h1b">TESTING</div>
  
  <!-- Begin Left Column -->

  <div class="page_content">
  <div class="left_column">
   <!-- <span class="h1b">SpaceWeb Developer Training
   </span>
   <br> -->

   <span class="h2b">Left Column</span>
 <p>
T-bone kevin meatloaf brisket ground round capicola filet mignon porchetta short loin. Pork chop filet mignon frankfurter porchetta, spare ribs shankle pancetta biltong meatloaf turkey doner short loin. Sausage pig hamburger porchetta, beef ribs shoulder prosciutto ground round bresaola cow pork chop. Brisket turducken chicken, ribeye pork chop boudin ham hock.
</p>
<p>
Alcatra meatloaf sirloin pork chop cupim pancetta. Ground round tenderloin meatloaf alcatra, flank biltong leberkas pork bacon sausage tongue chicken beef jowl. Bresaola drumstick hamburger ground round meatloaf. Alcatra short ribs leberkas kielbasa, ground round ham hock shankle bacon filet mignon pastrami chicken flank bresaola jerky landjaeger.
</p>
<p>
Turducken filet mignon venison bresaola, swine picanha drumstick. Fatback pancetta porchetta pig biltong. Ribeye tenderloin jowl, kielbasa salami meatball cupim andouille. Meatloaf shankle tail porchetta ham shank hamburger bacon, jowl picanha pork ribeye turducken tongue. Ribeye sirloin meatloaf, pork chicken boudin frankfurter shank cupim spare ribs. Pork chop turkey flank drumstick chuck salami pig filet mignon kielbasa corned beef kevin capicola sausage.
</p>
<p>
Beef kevin ham hock, tenderloin hamburger beef ribs sausage. Doner kielbasa sausage frankfurter, jowl turkey sirloin strip steak chicken turducken pancetta tri-tip beef ribs. Shankle pastrami alcatra, jerky fatback prosciutto rump pork chop chicken filet mignon picanha pork t-bone. Ribeye tongue tail, bresaola jowl fatback pork loin corned beef.
</p>
<span class="h2b">Left Column</span>
 <p>
T-bone kevin meatloaf brisket ground round capicola filet mignon porchetta short loin. Pork chop filet mignon frankfurter porchetta, spare ribs shankle pancetta biltong meatloaf turkey doner short loin. Sausage pig hamburger porchetta, beef ribs shoulder prosciutto ground round bresaola cow pork chop. Brisket turducken chicken, ribeye pork chop boudin ham hock.
</p>
<p>
Alcatra meatloaf sirloin pork chop cupim pancetta. Ground round tenderloin meatloaf alcatra, flank biltong leberkas pork bacon sausage tongue chicken beef jowl. Bresaola drumstick hamburger ground round meatloaf. Alcatra short ribs leberkas kielbasa, ground round ham hock shankle bacon filet mignon pastrami chicken flank bresaola jerky landjaeger.
</p>
<p>
Turducken filet mignon venison bresaola, swine picanha drumstick. Fatback pancetta porchetta pig biltong. Ribeye tenderloin jowl, kielbasa salami meatball cupim andouille. Meatloaf shankle tail porchetta ham shank hamburger bacon, jowl picanha pork ribeye turducken tongue. Ribeye sirloin meatloaf, pork chicken boudin frankfurter shank cupim spare ribs. Pork chop turkey flank drumstick chuck salami pig filet mignon kielbasa corned beef kevin capicola sausage.
</p>
<p>
Beef kevin ham hock, tenderloin hamburger beef ribs sausage. Doner kielbasa sausage frankfurter, jowl turkey sirloin strip steak chicken turducken pancetta tri-tip beef ribs. Shankle pastrami alcatra, jerky fatback prosciutto rump pork chop chicken filet mignon picanha pork t-bone. Ribeye tongue tail, bresaola jowl fatback pork loin corned beef.
</p>

  </div>
  <!-- End Left Column -->
  <!-- Begin Right Column -->
  <div class="right_column">
  <span class="h2b">Right Column</span>
 <p>
T-bone kevin meatloaf brisket ground round capicola filet mignon porchetta short loin. Pork chop filet mignon frankfurter porchetta, spare ribs shankle pancetta biltong meatloaf turkey doner short loin. Sausage pig hamburger porchetta, beef ribs shoulder prosciutto ground round bresaola cow pork chop. Brisket turducken chicken, ribeye pork chop boudin ham hock.
</p>
<p>
Alcatra meatloaf sirloin pork chop cupim pancetta. Ground round tenderloin meatloaf alcatra, flank biltong leberkas pork bacon sausage tongue chicken beef jowl. Bresaola drumstick hamburger ground round meatloaf. Alcatra short ribs leberkas kielbasa, ground round ham hock shankle bacon filet mignon pastrami chicken flank bresaola jerky landjaeger.
</p>
<p>
Turducken filet mignon venison bresaola, swine picanha drumstick. Fatback pancetta porchetta pig biltong. Ribeye tenderloin jowl, kielbasa salami meatball cupim andouille. Meatloaf shankle tail porchetta ham shank hamburger bacon, jowl picanha pork ribeye turducken tongue. Ribeye sirloin meatloaf, pork chicken boudin frankfurter shank cupim spare ribs. Pork chop turkey flank drumstick chuck salami pig filet mignon kielbasa corned beef kevin capicola sausage.
</p>
<p>
Beef kevin ham hock, tenderloin hamburger beef ribs sausage. Doner kielbasa sausage frankfurter, jowl turkey sirloin strip steak chicken turducken pancetta tri-tip beef ribs. Shankle pastrami alcatra, jerky fatback prosciutto rump pork chop chicken filet mignon picanha pork t-bone. Ribeye tongue tail, bresaola jowl fatback pork loin corned beef.
</p>
   
  <!-- End Right Column -->
  </div>
 <!-- Below is for the navigation buttons on the bottom of the screen. It goes BELOW the RIGHT COLUMN </div> -->
  <div class="bottom-nav-but clearfix">
     <div class="nav-but-left">
     <p class="nav-but-left-p">
     <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF" name="previous" id="previous1" type="button" value="&lt;&lt; Prev"onclick="page_navigation('previous')" class="round"/><br>
     <span  style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-left:1%;" id="previous_text1" class="style_bold"></span>
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-but-right">
     <p class="nav-but-right-p">
      <input style="background-color:#DFCFBF"  name="next" id="next1" type="button" value="Next &gt;&gt;"onclick="page_navigation('next')" class="round"/><br>
      <span style="padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;margin-right:1%;" id="next_text1" class="style_bold"></span>
     </p>
    </div>
 
  </div>
 <!-- Above is for the navigation buttons on the bottom of the screen --> 
 </div>
 
 </section>

</div>
<!-- End Container -->
 <!-- Begin Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
  <p>Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
 </div>
 <!-- End Footer -->

</body>

</html>
​
```

Updated to include clearfix class. Now the border encompasses more than the navigation divs.

Comment: Learn about floats and clearing floats. This will help you.

Comment: So I added .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}. Now the border shows around the div BUT it starts the border before the previous div. So the top border encompasses both the major_revison AND the top navigation. The bottom border encompasses both the left and right columns as well as the bottom navigation. The code above has been updated

Comment: You have to have to more divs with class clearfix. One between `#major_revision` and `.top-nav-but`, second one between `.right_column` and `.bottom-nav-but`

Comment: Actually I only needed to change the .clearfix:after to .clearfix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `clear: both` to your `top-nav-but` and `bottom-nav-but` classes:

```
.top-nav-but{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 2%;
    border:thin red solid;
    display:block;
    clear: both;
 }
.bottom-nav-but{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 2%;
    border:thin green solid
    clear: both;
}
```

The difference between `clear: both` and the `clearfix` class you're using, is that `clear: both` ensures the element clears any **preceeding** floated elements, and the `clearfix` class ensures any **internally** floated elements are cleared within the parent box (thereby ensuring that borders etc work as expected).

Comment: Thanks - As you were posting I was providing the same answer. I added the clear:both to the clearfix class instead of to each of the items.

Comment: To be honest I would advise against that - you're going to end up with an unnecessarily complex heirarchy of floats and clears that will be hard to maintain. Read up on when a "self clear" is appropriate, and when `clear: both` to clear other elements is best. Less is more!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a clearfix class. Makshh pointed me in the right direction. I came across the following posts which helped:

[CSS Layout - float and clear](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

[Clearing Floats: An Overview of Different Methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

Comment: Please see my answer also - yes, you could add `clearfix` all over the place, and that would probably work too, but your page layout is quite simple, so you don't need a lot of floats (left/right col and prev/next buttons only really). Remember that a `<DIV>` naturally has `auto` width and is a block level element, and only float where absolutely necessary!